# What is a better CRM than SalesForce that can sync to one user on Salesforce?

Tags: crm

I want a CRM that can be way faster to update contacts etc and go through my sales workday, but it needs to sync with a single user account on SalesForce.

This way I can replace SalesForce for my personal use, even though my company uses SalesForce and will not be changing.

Also with this new CRM I want to connect with Linkedin Sales Navigator with this new CRM to check existing Leads based on Name, Position, and Company.

For example, if I have lean Jane Doe from Company Inc, with position Retail Manager, then I want to confirm through LinkedIn is Jane Doe is still the current Retail Manager for Coimpany Inc, and if not, offer to update (but not automatically).

What is a good and reasonably priced CRM that will do these things?

Answer (score 1):

The first choice is Salesforce, but if you want to try something else, you should try HubSpot. HubSpot is a great tool to save data, and you can also sync LinkedIn Sales Navigator to HubSpot. This integration will not be free of cost, but you can still check with them.

Comment: Both salesforce and hubspot completely suck, they are the worst CRM.